# Trying to replace letters in string with question marks, but keep replacing whitespaces w/ question marks

Tags: java

I'm trying to write something to replace all letters in my string `msg` to question marks. When I run my program though, it replaces whitespace with question marks as well. In my if statement, I wanted to go for if it's a letter and not whitespace, replace with ?.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String msg = "FIG PKWC OIE GJJCDVKLC MCVDFJEHIY BIDRHYO.\n";
    int i;
    char let;

    for (i = 0; i < 43; ++i) {

        let = msg.charAt(i);
            if ( (Character.isLetter(let)) && ! (Character.isWhitespace(let)) ) {
                System.out.print('?');
            }
    }
}
```

My output for this is: ????????????????????????????????????

Any advice?

Comment: It's probably printing `?` for each letter. **But you are not printing anything for spaces**. You probably need an `else` block

Comment: Your code is not replacing anything. It is outputting question marks for letters but it is not outputting anything for non-letters. Add a `System.out.print(let);` in an `else` branch to at least also output the letters that weren't modified.

Comment: Your program is doing exactly what you wanted - it's outputting a `?` for every letter that isn't whitespace. Count the `?` characters - they match up exactly with the number of letters you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you only print '?' if the current character should be replaced by a '?', and print nothing otherwise.

You should also print the original characters not replaced by '?':

```
for (i = 0; i < msg.length(); ++i) {
    let = msg.charAt(i);
    if ( (Character.isLetter(let)) && ! (Character.isWhitespace(let)) ) {
        System.out.print('?');
    } else {
        System.out.print(let);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think about that! Wow, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Prog5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "FIG PKWC OIE GJJCDVKLC MCVDFJEHIY BIDRHYO.";
        //String decryptKey = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(msg.charAt(i))) {
                System.out.print("?");
            }else {
                System.out.print(msg.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add an explanation to your code. This will increase its usefulness and make it more likely to be upvoted :)